# How to edit permalink with str_replace() Function

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I'm trying to edit a wordpress permalink like the one here...

```
echo get_permalink();
```

This permalink as it is will output...

```
domain.com/directory/mycustompage/
```

I'm looking for a way using str_replace() to make the the URL to become...

```
domain.com/NEWDIRECTORY/?draft=mycustompage
```

So as you can see I want to change the middle directory to "NEWDIRECTORY" and also grab the last directory name "mycustompage" and use that as the parameter.

I apologise if this seems easy, I've just started seriously coding with PHP this year at school.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you edit it in the system rather than edit it on the fly?

Comment: What have your tried so far? Have you tried to `explode()` the string? With the resulting array, you should be able to achieve what you want.

Comment: Wordpress core creates the permalinks, editing that will be overwritten when updating. And I only need to do this the once.

Comment: No I don't mean edit the core, I mean update your site root to be correct

Comment: If it's only once then explode the string on `/` and rebuild it perhaps?

Comment: OK, I haven't got on to explode quite yet. Looking into it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you're after. I've put the URL in a variable and then exploded it and rebuilt it.

```
<?php
$url = "domain.com/directory/mycustompage/";
$exploded = explode('/', $url);
$newURL = $exploded[0].'/NEWDIRECTORY/?draft='.$exploded[2];

echo $newURL;
?>
```

Outputs `domain.com/NEWDIRECTORY/?draft=mycustompage` as requested

Comment: Haha no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I have and works! thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

```
$prev = get_permalink($prevID);
$prev = explode('/', $prev);
$prev = array_filter($prev);
$prev = array_merge($prev, array()); 
$prev = preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $prev);

$prev3 = $prev[3];
```

I then reconstruct the URL.